# How to overlay an image in HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, canvas

Basically I have two images that i need to display at the same time(and more later).
    
    
    
    var Canvas = function(canvasEl, width, height){
    this.el= canvasEl;
    this.el.width = width;
    this.el.height = height;
    this.ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
    }
    var canvas = new Canvas(document.querySelector("#mycanvas"), 1100, 650);

```
var add = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 500,-215);
};
add.src="add.png";
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();


if(datetime==1||datetime==13){
var clock1 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock1.png";
}

else if(datetime==2||datetime==14){
var clock2 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock2.png";
}

else if(datetime==3||datetime==15){
var clock3 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock3.png";
}

else if(datetime==4||datetime==16){
var clock4 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock4.png";
}

else if(datetime==5||datetime==17){
var clock5 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock5.png";
}

else if(datetime==6||datetime==18){
var clock6 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock6.png";
}

else if(datetime==7||datetime==19){
var clock7 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock7.png";
}

else if(datetime==8||datetime==20){
var clock8 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock8.png";
}

else if(datetime==9||datetime==21){
var clock9 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock9.png";
}

else if(datetime==10||datetime==22){
var clock10 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 600,100);
};
add.src="clock/clock10.png";
}
else if(datetime==11||datetime==23){
var clock11 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock11.png";
}

else if(datetime==12||datetime==0){
var clock12 = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
};
add.src="clock/clock12.png";
}

</script>
</body>
```

I have that currently and all it is supposed to do is have one image named "add.png" and another (based on the time) called "clock.png" to display at the same time in different locations on the canvas. The code works but it only shows the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need a separate .onload for each image--not just 1 add.onload**

```
// not always add.onload ...

add.onload ... add.src="add.png";
clock1.onload ... clock1.src="clock/clock1.png";
clock2.onload ... clock2.src="clock/clock2.png";

// same for clock3-12
```

Keep in mind that images are loaded asynchronously, so the load order of your images is not guaranteed to be the same as your code.  That may or may not be a problem depending on how the images fit together.

Here's an example of an image loader that guarantees all images are loaded and that the images are all in your specified order:

```
// image loader

var imageURLs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("add.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock1.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock2.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock3.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock4.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock5.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock6.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock7.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock8.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock9.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock10.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock11.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/clock12.png");

loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array holds your fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```